# How to store text file line by line into temporary list<string> after specific text

Tags: c#, wpf, list, read-data

I would like to store line by line from the text file after read it. However, the text that store into the temporary list must be after the ": ".

Below is the example of content in my text file:

```
Name: Johny
Age: 18
Favourite: Basketball, Food
```

I would like to store Johny as list[0], 18 as list[1], and etc.
For the Favourite, it should be store separately such as Basketball as list[2] and Food as list[3] and etc. This is because I need to place it back to different textBox afterward.

Below is my example code:

```
private void storeDataList()
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.DefaultExt = ".txt";
        ofd.Filter = "Text Document (*.txt) | *.txt";
        string filename = ofd.FileName;
        string line = "";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName);
            while (line != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    List<string> elements = new List<string>();
                    string readText = File.ReadAllText(filename);
                    i = readText.LastIndexOf(": ");
                    elements.Add[i];
                }
            }
            sr.Close();
            detailsTextBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `File.ReadAllLines` to read all lines from a text file. Use `string.Split` to split strings into substrings at specific separator characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

- read it line by line
- separate the fields and it's valued by splitting it with `:` delimiter
- check the line every three-line
- split the favorite value by comma delimiter `,`
- clean the value with `trim` to remove whitespaces

  ```
    private void storeDataList()
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.DefaultExt = ".txt";
        ofd.Filter = "Text Document (*.txt) | *.txt";
        string filename = ofd.FileName;
        string line = "";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            List<string> elements = new List<string>();

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName))
            {
                int rowNumber = 1;

                //Dynamically stop the loop until the end of the stream
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    //Split to separate field name and values
                    var textLine = reader.ReadLine().Split(':');

                    //Since favorite fields are in multiples of three, we re-split the value by comma every three line
                    if (rowNumber % 3 == 0)
                    {
                        var favouriteArr = textLine[1].Split(',');

                        for (int i = 0; i < favouriteArr.Length; i++)
                        {
                            //trim to clean whitespace
                            elements.Add(favouriteArr[i].Trim());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        elements.Add(textLine[1].Trim());
                    }
                    rowNumber++;
                }
            }

            // # just a new delimiter to print the elements in a text box
            detailsTextBox.Text = string.Join('#', elements);
        }
    }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner with LINQ that reads the file into lines, split the lines on `:` and takes what's after, then splits that on `,` for further granularity:

```cs
var output = File.ReadAllLines(filename).SelectMany(l => l.Split(':')[1].Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim());
```

Which outputs a list of: `Johny, 18, Basketball, Food`.

Comment: Just do `.ToList()` at the end, and it'll become a `List<string>`.